# List, Add, delete tasks with Google Tasks Api and VB Net (Not C#)

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, google-tasks-api

Im trying to do a form with buttons, listview (or datagridview) and some textbox to work with  tasks with Google Tasks Api but i cant find Visual Basic examples.

Can you show me a example of how to add a new task by pushing a button after fill some textbox (Name and detail)?

Thank you very much.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Calendar.VB.ConsoleApp/Program.vb?repo=samples

Comment: Its for calendar v3, now the api for tasks came separated